# Is it possible to display a field value as part of Views title?

Tags: views, entities

I'm building a block in Views where different brands show off their respective products, now I'm wondering if it's possible to pass a field value to the title.

I know that `%1` results in displaying the title

I've tried searching for a solution, but fail to find one as I'm not that familiar with the terminologies of Drupal (as in I don't really know what specifics to search for). This might be super simple, but I can't seem to find the answer and if possible it could become pretty useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a View's title is a theming issue. Have a look at [Views: how to programmatically change Views title?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33189/views-how-to-programmatically-change-views-title). The accepted answer is almost what you need. Add the function to your theme's `template.php` file (or your custom module if you don't have a custom theme yet).

The rest is simply coding. Store the field that you need as a variable `$my_field` and adapt the code from the referenced answer as follows:

```
function MY_THEME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME') {
    \\ Store your field: $my_field = ...
    $view->build_info['title'] = "YOUR TITLE" . $my_field;
  }
}
```

You can use the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to inspect `$view` in order to easily find the correct code for `$my_field`.